# Boost binding to member function of vector

Tags: c++, boost, lambda

Please help me with the following code. I need to add lengths of strings to a vector. I have no idea how to achieve it with boost. My best idea so far is:

```
boost::bind(add2Vect, boost::ref(lengths), L::_1)
```

Where add2Vect is a simple function that takes a vector, a string and add the length of the string to the vector. L is just a shorthand for boost::lambda

But this solution is bad, because I have to create a discrete function. That's not what lambdas should be about.

The code:

```
vector<string> strings;
strings.push_back("Boost");
strings.push_back("C++");
strings.push_back("Libraries");

vector<int> lengths;

for_each(strings.begin(), strings.end(),    
    // add lengths of strings to the vector 'lengths'

);

for_each(lengths.begin(), lengths.end(), 
    cout << L::_1 << " "
);
```

Comment: Do you even need `bind` or I am just not getting something. Your `for_each` could be replaced with an iterator loop going through `strings` and `push_back`ing `it->length()` onto `lengths`. Alternatively, something like `std::transform` would work well. Even better, instead of using a separate vector, use `strings` and call `length()` instead of having 2 copies.

Comment: Sure... ;-) It's just an example. I just want to know how to do it **using** boost:bind, lambda::bind or somehow else. It's an example from a book, and it should be easy..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Boost.Bind and Boost.Lambda are not the same thing.  You can't use lambda placeholders in bind unless you're using boost::lambda::bind.

Here's how you do what you seem to want:

```
std::transform(strings.begin(), strings.end(), std::back_inserter(lengths), 
               boost::bind(&std::string::size, _1));
```

If you really MUST use for_each:

```
std::for_each(strings.begin(), strings.end(), 
             boost::bind(&std::vector<int>::push_back,
               &lengths, boost::bind(&std::string::size, _1)));
```

But you should be using size_t rather than int.

Comment: Why can you use a lambda placeholder in a bind expression but not a bind placeholder inside a lambda?